# How do I make my bot repeat my message and delete the command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

As of right now, this is what I have.

```
@client.command()
async def say(ctx,*,message):
    await ctx.send(f"{message}")
```

This makes it so the bot will repeat what I say but I also want it to delete the command. so I want to be able to say `%say Hello, I'm a bot` and then the bot will delete that and repeat what I say. Any help on how to do that?

Comment: To add code formatting, use three backticks ``` and then the language name, like ```java and then another three backticks at the end of the code block

Answer (score 2):

What you appear to be wanting is

```py
@client.command()
async def say(ctx, message):
    await ctx.send(message)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

This will, in the case of the command `%say "Hello this is my message"`, return `Hello this is my message` and delete the original command.

As pointed out in the comments, this command will only print the text within the double-quotes. To fix this, you can use your original code just with the added `message.delete()`:

```py
@client.command()
async def say(ctx,*,message):
    await ctx.send(f"{message}")
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Information on the invocation context (ctx): https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#context

Information on the `Message` class: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message

Information on the `Message.delete()` method: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete

Information on the no-quotes syntax: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#variable

Comment: I don't think this will send the entire message, [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) specify that. 
The correct method would be `async def say(ctx, *, message)`.

Comment: @Ceres you are correct, which is why my original answer has quotes around the string sent to the command.